# Creating ordered factor based on values in various columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset which I obtained by exposing plants to different treatments. At the end of the experiment I scored whether the plant had survived, and if they survived, how many seeds they produced.
I will use ordered logit models to analyze the outcome. For that, I want to create a column with an ordered factor.In this factor I want to distinguish between plants that died, plants that survived but didn't form seeds, and plants that survived and formed seeds. 
Mock dataset and code I used:

```
df <-    data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),alive=c(0,0,1,1,1,1),seeds=c(0,0,0,0,15,14))
df$dead<-as.numeric(df$alive<1)
df$alive_no_seeds<-as.numeric(df$alive>0&df$seeds==0)
df$alive_seeds<-as.numeric(df$alive>0&df$seeds>0)
df$status<-as.character(df$dead>0="dead"&df$alive_no_seeds>0="alive_no_seeds"&df$alive_seeds>0="alive_seeds")
```

here is where things go wrong. I get

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "df$status<-as.character(df$dead>0="
```

If I get this factor I'd like to continue with:

```
ordered.status <- factor(status, levels=c("dead", "alive_no_seeds", "alive_seeds"), ordered=TRUE)
```

It probably is a simple syntax issue; I'd be very happy if someone could help me out. I have seen several posts were an ordered factor is based on values in single columns, but couldn't find a solution for my problem yet.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `df$alive<1="dead"` - what are you wanting to do in that statement?

Comment: Replace the last line of your first code chunk with: `df$status <- ifelse(df$alive < 1, "dead", ifelse(df$alive_no_seeds > 0, "alive_no_seeds", ifelse(df$alive_seeds > 0, "alive_seeds", NA)))`

Comment: Thanks Snubian, the name 'alive' is a bit misleading, if the value for alive is 0, the plant is dead.

Comment: Thanks kath, that already did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$status[df$alive<1] = 'dead'
df$status[df$alive>1 & df$alive_no_seeds==0] = "alive_no_seeds"
df$status[df$alive_no_seeds>0] = "alive_seeds"
```

something like this. Not sure in your data if alive or dead is 0